# Free search tool for static website

Tags: html, javascript, looking-for-a-script, search, site-search

I am looking for a free search tool for a website hosting html documentation files. the tool should display the results as listings of page title and few lines of text from that page. It should also work on the site being hosted locally on LAN so it should do the search by itself.

Comment: mysql + php an be use to create search.

Comment: but I dont have time to code, if I could get some scripts that i need to configure its fine

Comment: If this were asked today, I would close it because it is asking for recommendations.   Because it has been here so long, I've locked it for historical significance.

Answer (score 1):

We use [Sphider](http://www.sphider.eu/), it runs on PHP and MySQL, indexes static HTML files and can be run as a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a javascript site search [here](http://www.markus-olbrich.de/javascript/sitesearch/doc.html). The pros are: No database, no server side script. The drawbacks are: Sites must not be large, pages have to be XHTML and a site map must be present.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a [YaCy](http://www.yacy.net) peer

Answer (score 0):

I hooked into this one on Planet Source Code many years ago. It has worked very well for me for multiple pages. See: http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1998&lngWId=14